# GPIO Button not changing the light that is on

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I had trouble making out what I wanted to say in the title but I am currently trying to change the selection of lights that are turned on whenever the button is clicked that is on my breadboard.  Currently clicking the button does nothing despite my better judgment of the code is correct.  Since I am still learning how to work with Python, RaspPi, and such this is super frustrating.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN)  #GPIO pin for colour change
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN)  #GPIO for exit
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT) #GPIO Pin for red LED
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT) #GPIO Pin for blue LED

colorCheck = 0

try:
   while True:
    if ( GPIO.input(18) == True ):

        if (colorCheck < 3):
            colorCheck = colorCheck + 1;
        else:
            colorCheck = 1;

    if (colorCheck == 1):
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
    elif (colorCheck == 2):
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH)
    elif (colorCheck == 3):
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: add a pause with `time.sleep()`

Comment: @eyllanesc where would that go?

Comment: Inside while True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, explicitly comparing a boolean value to `True` (or `False`) is almost always a mistake.  It's completely pointless at best: the result of that comparison is itself a boolean value, why is that somehow usable, but the original value wasn't?  And it can be actively harmful, as you're throwing away Python's ability to treat a wide range of values as "truthy" (non-zero numbers, non-empty strings or containers, etc.).  In this particular case, the return value from `GPIO.input()` is actually an integer (0 or 1, I think), so comparing it to `True` guarantees that your code will never detect the button press.  So just write `if GPIO.input(18):` - note that those parentheses you're putting around all of your if's are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, as I am still learning that is a helpful thing to know.  I have got it all fixed now! The parentheses is just habit I guess.